# How do you change the textcolor of the list items in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, coding-style, themes, android-alertdialog, listpreference

Hello I am trying to change the text color of the items in a list on a `ListPreference` pop up window.  I have spent over an hour looking through all of the various style names but I can't find `TextAppearance` or anything that goes to this particular text.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: any idea what is the style for the ListPreference to use ? i can tell you i had the same issue with dialogs (background) and i found there is a C'tor that includes a theme as int for me to use so i could inherit from the original Dialog.Theme and change my own properties.

Comment: No, that is essentially my question, which style do I need to override in order to change the text color in the `ListView` for an `AlertDialog`

Comment: Since your question has to do with ListPreference and I have never done anything with that... I am not sure that this will help you... however, in reference to a ListView in an AlertDialog, I can help you with that.

http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/icon-list-in-alertdialog-t49975.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't. `*Preference` uses styles from `com.android.internal.R.styleable` which might be changed by manufactures. The idea of using the default ones is that every preference screen in your device look alike.

On the other hand you can try doing an `Activity` with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in your app's `AndroidManifest` and place a `ListView` styled as you want.

Comment: I haven't applied the theme to the Preference itself but the AlertDialog.  Theme looks great on all other AlertDialogs but the unfortunate side effect is `ListPreference` also uses an `AlertDialog` so I have my dark background now and the text is un-readable.  I can make a special case style for my `PreferenceActivity` that doesn't override the `AlertDialog` theme but it would be nice if it could match the rest of the app..

Comment: If you are changing the theme, just create a new activity with Theme.Dialog style and do whatever you want in it.

Comment: Preference.DialogPreference is the style of the parent of ListPreference, there doesn't sceem to be a direct style of the ListPreference. You can override that specific style in the theme and apply it to all activites, this wat you don't affect all AlertDialogs.

Comment: @Macarse The `ListPreference` isn't going to use my Theme.Dialog   @codeScriber thanks I'll look into that, you may need to throw that into an answer if it works :D

Comment: I never ment to use Theme.Dialog in a `ListPreference`. I tried to explain how to make a new activity using Theme.Dialog and making it look like a ListPreference.

Comment: Won't work this is the list preference in a preference activity with a bunch of other preferences as well.

Comment: Why? You can open activities from a preferenceActivity.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know which kind of `View` use `ListPreference`, probably it's something like `TextView`. If so than you could make smth like:

```
TextView textView;
String myString;
//....
SpannableString spanString=new SpannableString(myString);
spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, myString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spanString);
```

Comment: no this isn't the answer, first off how would you even get a reference to the `TextView` I am looking for a way to fix this through styles.  Thanks.